# Create multi LinearLayout that contains ConstraintLayout programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml

I want to create a list of things. Clearly, there is just a LinearLayout including ConstraintLayout and I want to duplicate LinearLayout because of that if I do not use LinearLayout as a parent of ConstraintLayout, components are overlap. I want to use LinearLayout as a row, ConstraintLayout as a area that contains components.

To sum up, I want to create LinearLayout instead of just creating ConstraintLayout. For now I can only create ConstraintLayout inside LinearLayout. I just want to create LinearLayout that includes ConstraintLayout each loop.

My XML codes here:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ParentLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/ContainerConstraintLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="25dp" >

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

My Java Codes here:

```
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = Objects.requireNonNull(getView()).findViewById(R.id.ContainerConstraintLayout);
    TextView[] title_textview = new TextView[5];
    CircleImageView circle_images[] = new CircleImageView[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        circle_images[i] = new CircleImageView(thiscontext);
        circle_images[i].setId(View.generateViewId());
        circle_images[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.waiter);
        circle_images[i].setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        circle_images[i].setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        constraintLayout.addView(circle_images[i]);

        title_textview[i] = new TextView(thiscontext);
        title_textview[i].setId(View.generateViewId());
        title_textview[i].setText("Title: " + i);
        title_textview[i].setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        constraintLayout.addView(title_textview[i]);
        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
        constraintSet.connect(title_textview[i].getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP);
        constraintSet.connect(title_textview[i].getId(), ConstraintSet.END, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.END);
        constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
    }
}
```